Wordpress Woocommerce 8.8.2 Shop page removes header
Wordpress Woocommerce (version 8.8.2) Shop page removes header.
I am using a custom created theme with wordpress blocks. Woocommerce shop page by default removes the heading navbar from the shop page. I am unable to customize the shop page in the editor either. Is there a way to add the heading navbar ?
In the functions.php file i have added the following.
// Add support for woocommerce
  add_theme_support('woocommerce');

// To enable gallery features add WooCommerce Product zoom effect, lightbox and slider support to our theme
 add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
 add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
 add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );


The cart page works fine header and footer are visible


Without seeing the code for your shop page, it will be hard to debug this. If you switch to a WP theme like twentytwentyfour, does the navigation appear on the shop page?

Post your header.php code
